# Call a case in php

Tags: php, switch-statement

i have a automatic bot script for a chat and i use switch() for switching to commands. Is it possible to call one of commands like this;

```
case '!pie':
sendMsg("Pie is great");
break;
case '!call':
sendMsg(call_switch($usersmg)); //call whatever the user said
break;
```

I don't want to manually add that, i want the users to be able to also call other commands on their own.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can add another switch statement within the '!call' case.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple cases can do the same thing, by letting it "fall through":

```
switch(something) {
    case '!pie':
    case '!call':
        sendMsg("Pie is great");
        break;
}
```

Alternatively, you can see if the command is "!call" before the switch, and change the command as needed before the switch is reached.

Comment: He doesn't want `!call == !pie`,  he wants to be able to call any case statement dynamically. (I'm not sure why).

Comment: @Martin: from what OP currently asked - this answer fits perfect. If OP wants something else - they need to ask it in a better way. Doesn't deserve -1 anyway

Comment: @zerkms The OP gave a simplified question which had just one case for the example. I thought it was quite a clear question, but perhaps I misunderstood

Comment: @Martin: the OP gave some strange example that doesn't explain anything particular using some strange terms. So I wouldn't even try to crticise another answers

Comment: guys, this is generally bad question, so don't bother yourself to figure out what OP had in his mind. There are a millions of right and wrong answers according to current form of question.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$input = '!call !pie';
$args = explode(' ', $input);

if ($args[0] == '!call' && count($args) > 1)
   array_shift($args);

switch ($args[0]) {
  case '!pie':
    ....
    break;
}
```

Comment: this works. thanks. your the only one here who understood! ty so much

Comment: No problem, honestly I thought the question was fairly clear... Although I don't see why the user couldn't just type !pie themselves rather than !call !pie. Hit the 'Accept' button if it has helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't call something unless it's a function. When a situation arise where you wish you could call another case, the solution is usually a function table. Instead of a large switch() statement, you have an array pointing to the function names with cases as the keys.

Incidentally, that's a change that PHP itself has undergone. In PHP 4, the VM uses a giant switch statement to handle opcodes. In PHP 5, a function table is used instead. Calling a  function incur the cost of stack-frame construction. The added flexibility often compensates for it though.